# Stack up against? What does this mean?

Tags: usage

> "Ted, it's really stacking up against you here, mate."

Does this mean that things are going unfavorable for Ted??

Situation: 
Ted is an suspect of a murder case and every evidence indicates he is a criminal. And a detective said this to Ted.

Comment: What was the context of this?  It's difficult to answer with no context.

Comment: You should read our [Details, Please...](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post and then edit this question to include some more details, like: Where did you find this? Did you look up "stack up" in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: Yes, we can say that things are going unfavourably for Ted. It does not mean he is guilty, but he probably should be looking for a good lawyer.  I hope the detective was not the one who called him 'mate'.

Comment: Another way to say it:  *The evidence is **mounting** against you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***It's*** stacking up against you

...is essentially a ["dummy it"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-it-is-a-dummy-it-in-this-sentence) usage (where ***it*** doesn't refer to anything in particular, just the surrounding situation / context in general (cf *It's good to be alive!, It's raining, etc.*)

The [phrasal] verb ***to stack [up]*** could usually be replaced by ***to pile [up], to accumulate,*** etc. But note the significance of immediately-following ***against*** - this strongly implies that what's happening is *contrary* (to you, your best interests). Which isn't always the case, as shown by...

> *...things are stacking up **for** you in **beneficial** ways.* <sub>[("Your Daily Horoscope" by Ebox Mauritius)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=G9tIW4q9I4fyUqbqu5gN&q=%22are%20stacking%20up%20for%20you%22&oq=%22are%20stacking%20up%20for%20you%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7328.8437.0.9069.5.5.0.0.0.0.101.387.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.FWE6R2Z_DI8)</sub>

---

It should by now be obvious that *it's really stacking up against you here* means *the current situation is looking increasingly bad for you*.

But I wouldn't have posted this answer purely to confirm OP's suspicion that it means *things are going unfavorable for Ted* (which should be ***unfavourably / unfavorably*** anyway).

I don't want to imply criticism of OP for *failing* to follow the implications of the word ***against***, or to consider the same construction with alternative "synonyms" for ***to stack [up]***. But I hope at least some users here might take note that even though it's notoriously difficult for non-Anglophones to actually ***use*** prepositions correctly in all contexts, you can often ***make use of*** the specific prepositions used in contexts where you're not sure about the meaning of other words nearby (in OP's specific case, by noting that ***against = not in favour***).

Answer (score 1):

evidence or a situation is said to stack up against someone in English.

This means: to form a pile of evidence or information that is not good for a person; it is against them.

Stack up can also have a more general meaning in AmE: to measure or compare.

Comment: As in *How does the Honda Accord stack up against the Toyota Camry?* or *He's sitting the bench because the coach feels he doesn't stack up.*